# Bitwise shift operation on a 128-bit number

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Lets say that I have an array of 4 32-bit integers which I use to store the 128-bit number

How can I perform left and right shift on this 128-bit number?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't use 2 `int64_t`? It'll make things much simpler than 4 `int32_t`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870491/x86-assembly-128bit-shifts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void shiftl128 (
    unsigned int& a,
    unsigned int& b,
    unsigned int& c,
    unsigned int& d,
    size_t k)
{
    assert (k <= 128);
    if (k >= 32) // shifting a 32-bit integer by more than 31 bits is "undefined"
    {
        a=b;
        b=c;
        c=d;
        d=0;
        shiftl128(a,b,c,d,k-32);
    }
    else
    {
        a = (a << k) | (b >> (32-k));
        b = (b << k) | (c >> (32-k));
        c = (c << k) | (d >> (32-k));
        d = (d << k);
    }
}

void shiftr128 (
    unsigned int& a,
    unsigned int& b,
    unsigned int& c,
    unsigned int& d,
    size_t k)
{
    assert (k <= 128);
    if (k >= 32) // shifting a 32-bit integer by more than 31 bits is "undefined"
    {
        d=c;
        c=b;
        b=a;
        a=0;
        shiftr128(a,b,c,d,k-32);
    }
    else
    {
        d = (c << (32-k)) | (d >> k); \
        c = (b << (32-k)) | (c >> k); \
        b = (a << (32-k)) | (b >> k); \
        a = (a >> k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fails for k > 32. You don't think a function would be better than a macro?

Comment: @MArtin: you're right, haven't though at that aspect or shifting  more than 32.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu and MArtin: Thanks a lot!

Comment: In addition to the shift larger than 32 problem mentioned, the macro versions have a number of common macro problems: the parameters used are not fully parenthesized, you may get undesired behavior if the parameters are not 32-bit types or are signed types, the macros are not 'statement safe' (they should be wrapped in a `do/while(0)` or similar). Also, the macros appear to perform shift operations, but the names suggest rotation - I'd find that confusing if I came across code using them. Anyone considering using them should take care to fix the problems.  Or use the function versions.

Comment: @Michael Burr: correct in every point. In fact I removed the macros, someone may find this post by google months from now and use them macros...

Comment: @Remus: I probably should have simply suggested that instead of mini-ranting.  I'll delete the comment (and this) in several minutes.

Comment: BTW, even the function version will not work if the 128bit integer stored in the 4 individual 32bit ints is 'signed'. Shiftr128 would have to fill with 1s, not 0s, if leftmost bit of 'a' is 1 and carry over the 1s across the 32bit chunks boundary...

Comment: @Michael Burr: I don't take that as a rant at all :) I've been burned by exactly those problems you mention many times, so I stand to shame for making the same mistakes myself. As for why I used ROT instead of SHIFT, was probably no later than yesterday I searched a very large code base for a macro/function to do a rot32 :), and I found the CRT was offering it already http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cc576c4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx...

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: There is still a bug in this code. The condition for recursing should be `if (k >= 32)`.

Comment: Try compiling with GCC 4.8 and above or Clang 3.2 and above ***using*** `-fsanitize=undefined`. UBsan is such a tattle tale ....

Answer (score 6):

Working with `uint128`? If you can, use the x86 SSE instructions, which were designed for exactly that. (Then, when you've bitshifted your value, you're ready to do other 128-bit operations...)

SSE2 bit shifts take ~4 instructions on average, with one branch (a case statement). No issues with shifting more than 32 bits, either. The full code for doing this is, using gcc intrinsics rather than raw assembler, is in `sseutil.c` ([github: "Unusual uses of SSE2"](https://github.com/mischasan/sse2)) -- and it's a bit bigger than makes sense to paste here.

The hurdle for many people in using SSE2 is that shift ops take immediate (constant) shift counts. You can solve that with a bit of C preprocessor twiddling ([wordpress: C preprocessor tricks](http://mischasan.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/the-c-preprocessor-not-as-cryptic-as-youd-think/)). After that, you have op sequences like:

```
LeftShift(uint128 x, int n) = _mm_slli_epi64(_mm_slli_si128(x, n/8), n%8)
```

for n = 65..71, 73..79, … 121..127
... doing the whole shift in two instructions.

Comment: You should show the relevant code rather than linking offsite. I tired going through your macro implementation, but it probably needs to be unrolled to make it clearer for visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a 128 bit number why not use a bitset? Using a bitset, you can adjust how big you want it to be. Plus you can perform quite a few operations on it.

You can find more information on these here:

http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/utility/bitset/start?do=backlink

Comment: @C Johnson I agree a bitset can be used, but I am looking at it from more of a logical standpoint and having those 4 32-bit ints as a constraint

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you're storing your 128-bit value in an array of 4 integers, you could do the following:

```
void left_shift(unsigned int* array)
{   
    for (int i=3; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        array[i] = array[i] << 1;

        if (i > 0)
        {
            unsigned int top_bit = (array[i-1] >> 31) & 0x1;
            array[i] = array[i] | top_bit;
        }
    }
}

void right_shift(unsigned int* array)
{   
    for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        array[i] = array[i] >> 1;

        if (i < 3)
        {
            unsigned int bottom_bit = (array[i+1] & 0x1) << 31;
            array[i] = array[i] | bottom_bit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're shifting by `n` bits and `n` is greater than or equal to 32, divide by 32 and shift whole integers. This should be trivial. Now you're left with a remaining shift count from 0 to 31. If it's zero, return early, you're done.

For each integer you'll need to shift by the remaining `n`, then shift the adjacent integer by the same amount and combine the valid bits from each.