# Understanding Left and Right Bitwise shift on a 128-bit number

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Artichoke101 [asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996384/bitwise-shift-operation-on-a-128-bit-number):

> Lets say that I have an array of 4 32-bit integers which I use to store the 128-bit number
>
> How can I perform left and right shift on this 128-bit number?"

My question is related to the answer Remus Rusanu gave:

```
void shiftl128 (
    unsigned int& a,
    unsigned int& b,
    unsigned int& c,
    unsigned int& d,
    size_t k)
{
    assert (k <= 128);
    if (k > 32)
    {
        a=b;
        b=c;
        c=d;
        d=0;
        shiftl128(a,b,c,d,k-32);
    }
    else
    {
        a = (a << k) | (b >> (32-k));
        b = (b << k) | (c >> (32-k));
        c = (c << k) | (d >> (32-k));
        d = (d << k);
    }
}

void shiftr128 (
    unsigned int& a,
    unsigned int& b,
    unsigned int& c,
    unsigned int& d,
    size_t k)
{
    assert (k <= 128);
    if (k > 32)
    {
        d=c;
        c=b;
        b=a;
        a=0;
        shiftr128(a,b,c,d,k-32);
    }
    else
    {
        d = (c << (32-k)) | (d >> k); \
        c = (b << (32-k)) | (c >> k); \
        b = (a << (32-k)) | (b >> k); \
        a = (a >> k);
    }
}
```

Lets just focus on one shift, the left shift say. Specifically,

```
a = (a << k) | (b >> (32-k));
b = (b << k) | (c >> (32-k));
c = (c << k) | (d >> (32-k));
d = (d << k);
```

How is this left shifting the 128-bit number? I understand what bit shifting is, << shifts bits left, (8-bit number) like 00011000 left shifted 2 is 01100000. Same goes for the right shift, but to the right. Then the single "pipe" | is OR meaning any 1 in either 32-bit number will be in the result.

How is `a = (a << k) | (b >> (32-k))` shifting the first part (32) of the 128-bit number correctly?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the `32` I would advise using `sizeof(unsigned int)`. It should be `32`, but at least you'll make sure of it.

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned int)` would be 4. :) So, you need `sizeof(unsigned int)*CHAR_BIT`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This technique is somewhat idiomatic.  Let's simplify to just `a` and `b`.  We start with:

```
+----------+----------+
|    a     |    b     |
+----------+----------+
```

and we want to shift left some amount to obtain:

```
+----------+----------+
|  a    :  |  b    :  |  c  ...
+----------+----------+
|<--x-->|  |
      ->|y |<-
```

So `X` is simply `a << k`.  `y` is the `k` msbs of `b`, right-aligned in the word.  You obtain that result with `b >> (32-k)`.

So overall, you get:

```
a = x | y
  = (a << k) | (b >> (32-k))
```

*[Note: This approach is only valid for 1 <= `k` <= 31, so your code is actually incorrect.]*

Comment: Hence the guard in the above code that recursively calls itself when k is larger than 32.  Not the fastest way, but it is what it is ;)

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: It needs to check for `k >= 32`.  And it doesn't handle the other special case of `k == 0`.

Comment: Wow, the visual example helps a lot. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

When the bits of `a` get shifted to the left, something has to fill in the space left over on the right end. Since `a` and `b` are conceptually *adjacent* to each other, the void left by shifting the bits of `a` gets filled by the bits that are shifted off the end of `b`. The expression `b >> (32-k)` computes the bits that get shifted off of `b`.

Comment: Thanks for adding the sources! :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that it is acceptable, in shifting, to "lose" data.

The simplest way to understand shifting is to imagine a window. For example, let us work on bytes. You can view a byte as:

```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 a b c d e f g h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                 [      B        ]
```

Now, shifting is just about moving this window:

```
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 a b c d e f g h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [     B >> 8    ]
   [     B >> 7    ]
     [     B >> 6    ]
       [     B >> 5    ]
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 a b c d e f g h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         [     B >> 4    ]
           [     B >> 3    ]
             [     B >> 2    ]
               [     B >> 1    ]
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 a b c d e f g h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                   [     B << 1    ]
                     [     B << 2    ]
                       [     B << 3    ]
                         [     B << 4    ]
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 a b c d e f g h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                           [     B << 5    ]
                             [     B << 6    ]
                               [     B << 7    ]
                                 [     B << 8    ]
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 a b c d e f g h 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If you look at the direction of the arrows, you can think of it as having a fixed window and a moving content... just like your fancy mobile phone touch screen!

So, what is happening in the expression `a = (a << k) | (b >> (32-k))` ?

- `a << k` selects the `32 - k` rightmost bits of `a` and move them toward the left, creating a space of `k` 0 on the right side
- `b >> (32-k)` selects the `k` leftmost bits of `b` and move them toward the right, creating a space of `32 - k` 0 on the left side
- the two are merged together

Getting back to using byte-length bites:

- Suppose that `a` is `[a7, a6, a5, a4, a3, a2, a1, a0]`
- Suppose that `b` is `[b7, b6, b5. b4, b3, b2, b1, b0]`
- Suppose that `k` is `3`

The number represented is:

```
// before
 a7 a6 a5 a4 a3 a2 a1 a0 b7 b6 b5 b4 b3 b2 b1 b0
[           a           ]
                        [           b           ]

// after (or so we would like)
 a7 a6 a5 a4 a3 a2 a1 a0 b7 b6 b5 b4 b3 b2 b1 b0
         [           a           ]
                                 [           b           ]
```

So:

- `a << 3` does actually become `a4 a3 a2 a1 a0  0  0  0`
- `b >> (8 - 3)` becomes `0  0  0  0  0 b7 b6 b5`
- combining with `|` we get `a4 a3 a2 a1 a0 b7 b6 b5`

rinse and repeat :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the else case k is guaranteed to be 32 or less. So each part of your larger number can actually be shifted by k bits. However, shifting it either left or right makes the k higher/lower bits 0. To shift the whole 128bit number you need to fill these k bits with the bits "shifted out" of the neighboring number.

In the case of a left shift by k, the k lower bits of the higher number need to be filled with the k upper bits of the lower number. to get these upper k bits, we shift that (32bit) number right by 32-k bits and now we got those bits in the right position to fill in the zero k bits from the higher number.

BTW: the code above assumes that an unsigned int is exactly 32 bits. That is not portable.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, consider a 16-bit unsigned short, where we store the high and low bytes as `unsigned char h, l` respectively.
To simplify further, let's just shift it left by one bit, to see how that goes.

I'm writing it out as 16 consecutive bits, since that's what we're modelling:

```
[h7 h6 h5 h4 h3 h2 h1 h0 l7 l6 l5 l4 l3 l2 l1 l0]
```

so, `[h, l] << 1` will be

```
[h6 h5 h4 h3 h2 h1 h0 l7 l6 l5 l4 l3 l2 l1 l0 0]
```

(the top bit, h7 has been rotated off the top, and the low bit is filled with zero).
Now let's break that back up into `h` and `l` ...

```
[h, l] = [h6 h5 h4 h3 h2 h1 h0 l7 l6 l5 l4 l3 l2 l1 l0 0]
=> h = [h6 h5 h4 h3 h2 h1 h0 l7]
     = (h << 1) | (l >> 7)
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

my variant for logical left shift of 128 bit number in little endian environment:

```
typedef struct { unsigned int component[4]; } vector4; 
vector4 shift_left_logical_128bit_le(vector4 input,unsigned int numbits) {
    vector4 result;
    if(n>=128) {
         result.component[0]=0;
         result.component[1]=0;
         result.component[2]=0;
         result.component[3]=0;
         return r;
    }
    result=input;
    while(numbits>32) {
        numbits-=32;
        result.component[0]=0;
        result.component[1]=result.component[0];
        result.component[2]=result.component[1];
        result.component[3]=result.component[2];
    }
    unsigned long long temp;
    result.component[3]<<=numbits;
    temp=(unsigned long long)result.component[2];
    temp=(temp<<numbits)>>32;
    result.component[3]|=(unsigned int)temp;
    result.component[2]<<=numbits;
    temp=(unsigned long long)result.component[1];
    temp=(temp<<numbits)>>32;
    result.component[2]|=(unsigned int)temp;
    result.component[1]<<=numbits;
    temp=(unsigned long long)result.component[0];
    temp=(temp<<numbits)>>32;
    result.component[1]|=(unsigned int)temp;
    result.component[0]<<=numbits;
    return result;
}
```